# Populating RecyclerView with Firestore Collection but ordered by it's subcollection

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Firestore Database in my Chat App. And currently am using the Firebase UI RecylerAdapter.

And this is what my Data Structure looks like:

```
    Chats (Collection)

       --> CHAT_ID (Document)

              --> Members (SubCollection)

                     --> MEMBER_ID (Document)

              --> Messages (SubCollection)

                     --> MESSAGE_ID (Document)
                            --> msg  : Some Message
                            --> time : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Now I want to query the database in such a way that it populates the recyclerview with the Chats collection but select only those documents which have the **Current userid as the MEMBER_ID** in the Members subcollection and **ordered by the Field time** in the **last msg** in the Messages subcollection.

I hope that makes sense.

Here is the screenshot of the database:
[image]

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it.

Comment: Ok i did now please help me out
@AlexMamo

Comment: You also say: *in such a way that it populates the RecyclerView with the Chats collection* but I cannot see any "Chats" collection in your screenshot. Is it "Private Messages" instead? Or simply "Messages" subcollection?

Comment: Yeah ```Chats``` collection is Private ```Messages``` collection
@AlexMamo

Comment: I got that. As I see, you already got an answer, which indeed can solve your use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to query one collection based on information from another collection. You will either have to replicate the member information into the `CHAT_ID` document, or set up an inverse mapping (`USERS --> USER_ID --> CHATS --> CHAT_ID`).

Comment: What if I put all the members of the ```Chat_ID``` document in a field ```Members``` as an array and then use ```db.collection(Chats).whereArrayContains("members", USER_ID)```. I think that should work

Comment: That's what I meant with "replicate the member information into the `CHAT_ID` document", and that's indeed one solution.

Comment: Another issue
```Query query = db.collection("Chats").whereEqualTo("type", "dm").whereEqualTo("members", Arrays.asList(CAID, UAID)).limit(1).get()```
I used this query but the problem is the Array list may be like (UAID, CAID). And i want the specific document where there exists **only these two IDs**. How am i supposed to join them with a logical ```OR```. I used ```whereEqualTo()``` method because the ArrayContain and ArrayContainAny also return the documents where these two are a part of it and other IDs are also in the array

Comment: If the values in the array are in a pre-determined order (e.g. alphabetical), you can use that order in your code too before sending the query. If there's no pre-determined order, there is no way to do this query on an array. You could consider created a separate field where you concatenate the values (in alphabetical order) and use that for this query.